# Android SQLite not returning data for given search term

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to build a search interface but the SQLite database returns nothing here is the code for **search function**

```
public List<DiaryModel> searchData(String srchTerm){
    List<DiaryModel> data2=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql="SELECT * FROM "+DB_TABLE+" WHERE "+KEY_HEADING+" LIKE '"+srchTerm+"%'";
    Cursor cursor2 =db1.rawQuery(sql,null);
    cursor2.moveToFirst();
    StringBuilder stringBuffer2;
    stringBuffer2 = new StringBuilder();
    DiaryModel diaryModel2;
    while (cursor2.moveToNext()){
        diaryModel2 = new DiaryModel();
        String heading = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("heading"));
        String desc = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("desc_"));
        diaryModel2.setHeading(heading);
        diaryModel2.setDesc(desc);
        stringBuffer2.append(diaryModel2);
        data2.add(diaryModel2);
    }
    return data2;
}
```

but when I print everything the Database returns data, here is the code for **get Data** used for printing data present in Database

```
public List<DiaryModel> getdata(){
    List<DiaryModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM diary_db", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    DiaryModel diaryModel;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        diaryModel = new DiaryModel();
        String heading = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_HEADING));
        String desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_DESC));
        diaryModel.setHeading(heading);
        diaryModel.setDesc(desc);
        stringBuffer.append(diaryModel);
        data.add(diaryModel);
    }
    return data
}
```

The thing is only this SQL statement is working

```
SELECT * FROM diary_db
```

and if any condition is put nothing returns.

Comment: Your intention is that the items start with the search term? If not then try `String sql="SELECT * FROM "+DB_TABLE+" WHERE "+KEY_HEADING+" LIKE '%"+srchTerm+"%'";` i.e. wild character added to start. This will find the search term anywhere in the column.

Comment: @MikeT I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something that you are doing wrong in both methods:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

and then:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
.................
}
```

This way you miss the 1st row of the results, because after you move the cursor to the 1st row, you move once again to the next row.  
So delete this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

from both methods.